# optimize htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, optimization

I have two condition which are conflict

```
RewriteRule ^patients/findadoctor/(.*)\.html$  subcategorydoctor.php?id=$1 [L,NC] and
RewriteRule ^patients/findadoctor/(.*)\.html$  specilitydoctor.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

How do I set condition for that? I am doing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/patients/findadoctor/radiationoncology\.html$ [OR]   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/patients/findadoctor/paediatricsurgery\.html$ [OR]   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/patients/findadoctor/generalsurgery\.html$ [OR]      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/patients/findadoctor/neurosurgery\.html$ [OR]   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/patients/findadoctor/neurology\.html$ [OR]   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/patients/findadoctor/paediatrics\.html$ [OR]   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/patients/findadoctor/paediatriccardiology\.html$ [OR]   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/patients/findadoctor/paediatriccardiacanaesthesiology\.html$ [OR]        
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/patients/findadoctor/paediatriccardiovascularthoracicsurgery\.html$ [OR]     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/patients/findadoctor/bonemarrowtransplant\.html$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/patients/findadoctor/kidneytransplant\.html$ [OR]      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/patients/findadoctor/cardiacanaesthesiology\.html$
RewriteRule ^patients/findadoctor/(.*)\.html$ subcategorydoctor.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: They shouldn't conflict if you have different RewriteCond directives?

Comment: For your first rule (ie. `subcategorydoctor.php`) you've listed a set of conditions under which that rule should be triggered. You would need to list a similar (but different) set of conditions for the second rule (ie. `specilitydoctor.php`) - but you've not indicated what these conditions are in the question. ie. Under what conditions should the `specilitydoctor.php` script be run?